# Error al Enviar Factura Electrónica a la DIAN

Tags: xml, webservice, firma-digital

estoy enviando el archivo xml al webservice de la DIAN, pero me está devolviendo con el siguiente mensaje y código de respuesta no sé como solucionar este aspecto. Muchas gracias

```
<ns2:EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta xmlns:ns2="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura" xmlns:ns3="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ConsultaDocumentos" xmlns:ns4="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/VersionDespliegue">
        <ns2:Version>Componente DIAN</ns2:Version>
        <ns2:ReceivedDateTime>2018-10-17T15:44:49.227-05:00</ns2:ReceivedDateTime>
        <ns2:ResponseDateTime>2018-10-17T15:44:49.681-05:00</ns2:ResponseDateTime>
        <ns2:Response>100</ns2:Response>
        <ns2:Comments>El ejemplar no se pudo acceder</ns2:Comments>
    </ns2:EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta>
```

Comment: [edit] la pregunta con el código que estás usando para enviar el archivo XML. Sin mas detalles, creo que este es un problema de cómo estás armando el XML o los parámetros del servicio. Revisa si la DIAN tiene documentación de este servicio.

Comment: Parece ser que es un problema con el XML que va codificado en la petición SOAP. De todas maneras, solo podemos saberlo si vemos un ejemplo de la petición enviada al Web Service. Y te puede ayudar si etiquetas la pregunta con la etiqueta 'dian'

Comment: Debes revisar si estas enviando en formato zip y convertido en base64

Comment: Jairo, buen día. Tengo el mismo problema que mencionas aquí, lograste darle solución que me la pudieras compartir. Gracias.